# Issues with autorole using Quick.db (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make an autorole code using quick.db, but it returns the error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes`
**My "setautorole" command:**

```js
      const role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0])
      if(!role) return message.channel.send('I couldnt find the role')
db.set(`autorole`, role)
message.channel.send('The process worked fine!')
```

**This is on index of bot:**

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  let few = db.get(`autorole_${member.guild.id}`)
  if(few === null) return;
  member.roles.add(few)
})
```

Well, I don't know what to do to fix this error, I need a little help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better just to save the role ID in Database

BTW you're doing it all wrong. It should be like
**setautorole.js**

```js
const role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]);
if(!role){
    return( message.channel.send('I couldnt find the role') );
}
db.set(`autorole_${message.guild.id}`, role.id);
message.channel.send('The process worked fine!');
```

**index.js**

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  let roleID = db.get(`autorole_${member.guild.id}`)
  if(!roleID) return;
  role = member.guild.roles.find(roleID);
  if(!role){
     console.log("That role dosen't exist");
     return (false);
  }
  member.roles.add(role)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea Akio, but, i i did something like:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  let roleID = db.get(`autorole_${member.guild.id}`)
  if(!roleID) return;
 let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === roleID);
  if(!role){
     console.log("That role dosen't exist");
     return (false);
  }
  member.roles.add(role)
})
```

and worked, thanks for help :)